# How to Create Button beside new button in Object view

Tags: custom-object

[image]

can i create button in place of Yellow colour.pls let me know.

Comment: If i Click that button,it has to redirected to custom vf page.

Comment: is it possible?!

Comment: its possible but not in recent view.

Comment: in recent view?!is it not posssible

Comment: No recent view not possible in other list view possible.